# Downloading/Uploading inventory from Amazon

Tags: c#, download, upload, inventory, amazon-product-api

When selling on Amazon there is an inventory list, and when having large amounts of products it can be very time consuming to change listings e.g. when new stock comes in. I have been stuck on this for days. I would like to make a small program (most likely on c#). Here is what I am trying to accomplish: 
1. Program starts and logs in to Amazon seller.
2. Downloads the inventory of my products for sale.
3. Compare and update the downloaded file with the one I already have with my new stock.
4. Upload the updated file.
Step 1,2,4 are the ones I need big help, as I been stuck for long time now, step 3 is aright, I know how to read and save the file, just need to learn how to update.

Answer (score 0):

Are you ask how to use a program to upload or update to your amazon account storage?

Comment: I'm trying to make one, but I am unsure how to, so I'm seeking help to make it.

Comment: If you are using winform for c#, i have a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio.net

First you need to download AWSSDK for .net and add to reference

Following is sample code to upload your files

```
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(<awsAccessKeyId>, <awsScrectKey>, RegionEndpoint.APNortheast1);

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"uploadFolder");
        int count = 1;
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (count % 8 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("upload " + count.ToString() + "/" + files.Length.ToString() + ".." + file.Replace("uploadFolder\\", ""));
                PutObjectRequest requestd = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = "yourBucketName",
                    Key = file.Replace("uploadFolder\\" , ""),
                };
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    requestd.InputStream = stream;

                    // Put object
                    PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(requestd);
                }
                // Set Canned ACL (PublicRead) for an existing item
                client.SetACL(new SetACLRequest
                {
                    BucketName = "yourBucketName",
                    Key = file.Replace("uploadFolder\\", ""),
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                });
            }
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I misunderstood your question, I am after both downloading and uploading. AWS is free to sign but its pay per use, I'm sure there is a lot of other people which will find this useful but I was after different method. By the way your code looks good its just misplaced closing bracket in "client.SetACL(new SetACLRquest ..." and following lines.

Comment: As example I will talk about a different site to make the method understandable: I open the program, it pops up asking for login and username, next it access "https://www.dreamspark.com/Account/SignIn.aspx" page (sign in) and uses the already provided data to login, then it goes to inventory tab (where there is one program as replacement for the list on amazon) and then "clicks" on the download button.That was for downloading rest I hope is self explanatory and I'm back to Amazon site. Next it compares downloaded file with my file. Then it goes back to inventory and uploads the updated file.